# Hilbert transform of a Hermite function. Show that $\hat{h}_n(\omega)=(-i)^nh_n(\omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

The Hermite functions are given by $$h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x),$$ where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermite polynomial of of degree $n$. Show that $$\hat{h}_n(\omega)=(-i)^nh_n(\omega).$$

So far I've got:

A Hermite polynomial of degree $n$ is given by $H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})$.  Then $$h_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}e^{-x^2/2}(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2}).$$
The Hilbert transform of this is $\mathscr{H}\{h_n(x)\} = h_n(x)\mathscr{H}\{H_n(x)\}$ due to the nature of the Hilbert transform of the product of two functions.  Now, we determine the Hilbert transform of an $n$ degree Hermite polynomial.
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{H}\{H_n(x)\} &= \mathscr{H}\left\{(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})\right\}\\ &= (-1)^n2\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^\infty \omega^n e^{-\pi^2t^2}\sin{\left(\omega x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}dt\\ &= (-1)^n2\sqrt{\pi}\sin{\left(\omega x+\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}\int_0^\infty \omega^n e^{-\pi^2t^2}
\end{align*}

Am I even on the right track?  How do I proceed?

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to find the answer to this question.  Following http://fuchs-braun.com/media/d9140c7b3d5004fbffff8007fffffff0.pdf you can recursively find what you want, but it does not give a general expression of the Hilbert transformed Hermite functions valid for any n.